# javascript slicing an array on content

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way to slice with javascript an array but not according to the index of the dimension but according to the content of its' j-th element (supposedly uniqueness of values)?

Example:

```
myArray = [["a", "b", "c"], ["car", "hat", "plate"], ["red", "green", "black"]]
```

Slicing `myArray` on `0,1` will give

```
[["c"],["plate"],["black"]]
```

and slicing on `"black"` should give the same result.

What is the use of my question? Say for example that my array comes from parsing the rows of a file and I want to slice upon the headers (first row), but the headers of the -to be parsed- files (although same) come in random orders.

Thanks

Comment: you can get the index using `Array.indexOf('plate')`

Comment: What are the meaning of the parameters `0, 1`?  And why do these parameters produce the same value as calling with `'black'` as a parameter?

Comment: Also, don't redefine `Array`; it's a constructor for arrays and redefining it will break a lot of things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply loop through the 2D array and call `slice(j)` on each array:

```
for(item in myArray)
    Array[item] = myArray[item].slice(2);
```

Here is an example snippet:

```js
var myArray = [["a", "b", "c"], ["car", "hat", "plate"], ["red", "green", "black"]];

for(item in myArray)
    myArray[item] = myArray[item].slice(2);

console.log(myArray);
```

Using `"black"` as a paramter involes going through each array and finding such an element. When you find a match simply call `indexOf()` to get the proper `index` and use that, which will be `2`:

```
var index = "black";

for(item in myArray)
    if(myArray[item].indexOf(index) != -1)
        index = myArray[item].indexOf(index);

// index = 2
```

*Note:* There will be problems when there is more than a single `"black"`, in this case `index` will be the last `"black"` found in `myArray`.

Comment: This code happens to produce the right answer for the example, but it doesn't really make sense with some of the details of the question: namely, the parameters to the slice function (`0, 1` and `'black'`).

Comment: @NoahFreitas I think the OP means by `0,1` as to remove items in the `0,1` index and keep the ones at `2`. and `'black'` simply being the 2nd element of one of the arrays.

Comment: @NoahFreitas : You are correct `Noah`, I want to use `"black"` as a parameter and through time it may be on different indexes which I do not know.

Comment: @pebox11, and you want all the other arrays filtered down to only the value at the same index as `'black'`?

Comment: @pebox11, this code does not currently do that, since it has the index (`2`) hard-coded. @codeSun's answer does suggest how to do this.

Comment: @NoahFreitas Updated, I've added how to do that.

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek : quoting from [-1-](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) : Because the order of iteration is implementation-dependent, iterating over an array may not visit elements in a consistent order...

Comment: @pebox11 That's true, but in this case our for loop is going to go over all the elements anyways. The order it goes through it being possibly inconsistent doesn't matter in this case. You can use just a normal `for( var i = 0; i<myArray.length; i++ ) { ... }` if you wish to, the use of `for..in` wasn't really the point of my solution, as it will work fine either way. I mostly will use it for the readability. But in most cases it's used for object iteration.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use value of array element for search, use indexOf().

```
 myArray = [["a", "b", "c"], ["car", "hat", "plate"], ["red", "green", "black"]];

    var index = myArray.indexOf("black");

    for(value in myArray)
        myArray[value] = myArray[value].slice(index);
```